# Press Delete Key from JS button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

there is an editable HTML table, so when a user selects any row from and clicks delete from the keyboard it deletes the row, the same thing should be done through a button i.e when the user selects any row and clicks the delete button, the row should be deleted.

```
<table class="double" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" id="demoTable"></table>
<p>
    <button id="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="deleteRows()">Delete Row</button>
</p>
```

Comment: You don't want to simulate a [Delete] button press, instead manipulate the DOM directly to remove the `<tr>` element.

Comment: @Dai seems a lot better to invoke the same core functionality. The delete button might be doing more than just removing the DOM node - it might involve validation, server request, wait for response, updating an internal model representation, maybe even capture statistics, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add this code in you JS code

```
$scope.deleteRow = function () {
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var selectedObj = range.startContainer.wholeText;
            var table = document.getElementById("demoTable");
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                var tableRow = table.rows[i];
                var found = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
                    var getElem = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML
                    if (selectedObj === getElem) {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (found) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("demoTable").deleteRow(i); //deleted the row 
        }
```